# JSTL - Iterate over a list displaying items on two columns

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a list, let's say it contains these elements : {A,B,C,D,E,F}, and I want to display them on a jsp page in a two columns (using , not table), in this way

```
A  B
C  D
E  F
```

I thought as something like this but it's not working:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}" varStatus="loopCounter">          
    <div>
        <div>${item.key}&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>${item.value}</b></div>
    </div>
    <c:if test="${loopCounter.count%2 ==0}">
        <BR>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: loopCounter.index would be the counting item. If you test `%2 == 0` you'll get a break after the first item.

Comment: what is not working

Answer (score -1):

You say `${list}` is a List,
but you tried to access it like a Map with `${item.key}` and `${item.value}`.

I suppose you are mixing the both, and therefore you don't get what you expect.

Below are two examples with list and map, how to display content like a table:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>table with modulo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .psydoTableCell {
        float:left; 
        margin-left:10px;
        display: table-cell;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<%
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("D");
    list.add("E");
    list.add("F");
    pageContext.setAttribute("list", list);
%>
    <h3>iterate a list</h3>
    <div>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${list}" varStatus="loopCounter">          
            <div class="psydoTableCell">${item}</div>
            <c:if test="${loopCounter.count %2 == 0}">
                <br>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
<%
    Map<String,String> map =new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("a", "1");
    map.put("b", "2");
    map.put("c", "3");
    map.put("d", "4");
    pageContext.setAttribute("map", map);
%>
    <h3>iterate a map</h3>
    <div>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${map}" varStatus="loopCounter">          
            <div class="psydoTableCell">${item.key}</div>
            <div class="psydoTableCell">${item.value}</div>
            <br>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Output:

> **iterate a list**
>
> A B
>     C D
>     E F
>
> **iterate a map**
>
> a 1
>    b 2
>    c 3
>    d 4